# PG_DUMP to Skip Certain Items in PG_LARGEOBJECT?

Tags: postgresql, blob, pg-dump

I am newer to PostgreSQL than Oracle.  So, I'm going to explain what I do in Oracle and then ask if anyone knows if there is a way to do this in PostgreSQL.

I have over 300 tables in Oracle.  Of them, some contain LOBs.  Two of the ones I know, which consume a ton of space to house PDFs, are called *JP_PDFS* and *JP_PRELIMPDFS*.  When I need a copy of this database DMP to transport to someone else, I don't need the contents of these tables to do a majority of so many other troubleshooting steps.  So, I can export this database in two DMP files; one with the exclude directive and one with the include + content directives:

`expdp full=n schemas=mySchema directory=DMPs dumpfile=mySchema_PDFS_schema.dmp logfile=expdp1.log include=TABLE:"IN('JP_PDFS','JP_PRELIMPDFS')" content=metadata_only`

`expdp full=n schemas=mySchema directory=DMPs dumpfile=mySchema_noPDFS.dmp logfile=expdp2.log exclude=TABLE:"IN('JP_PDFS','JP_PRELIMPDFS')"`

Unfortunately, all LOBs are stored in PG_LARGEOBJECT.  The references/pointers to the actual LO rows that comprise the LOB is stored in the aforementioned tables.  But, there ARE other tables with LOBs I **DO** need to be exported to the .backup file with pg_dump.

What I want is a way to do what I do in the Oracle world with PostgreSQL. I know how to export the schemas, only, for JP_PDFS and JP_PRELIMPDFS. But, is there a way to tell pg_dump to not include the objects from PG_LARGEOBJECT for the referenced items from both JP_PDFS and JP_PRELIMPDFS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, large objects don't “belong” to anybody. Either all of them are dumped (for a dump of the complete database ot if the `-b` option of `pg_dump` was used) or none.

Large objects are cumbersome and require a special API. If the size of your binary data doesn't exceed 1GB, consider using the data type `bytea` for them. That is much easier to handle and will work like you expect.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, the data model is already baked-in - so changing how those LOBs are stored is the way I have to deal with it.

Again, I appreciate your knowledge and response.  I'm just sad there isn't another way.